# How to make Cocos2D can search resources in a specific path?

Tags: url, resources, cocos2d-iphone

My app gets some resources, specifically `.pvr.ccz`, from URL and save them in `Documents` directory.

```
NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
...
[responseObject writeToFile:[documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", <file_name>, @"pvr.ccz"]] options:NSAtomicWrite error:nil];
```

After that creates a sprite using `.plist` and `.pvr.ccz`. The list of `.png` images specified in the property list which is already in the project.

```
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"<property_list_name>.plist"];
CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<file_name>.png"]];
```

This will be warned that `-[CCFileUtils fullPathFromRelativePath:resolutionType:] : cocos2d: Warning: File not found: <file_name>.pvr.ccz`

Is there any way to make Cocos2D can search the resources from URL that saved in a specific folder? or is there any way to save the resources from URL in the place where Cocos2D can found them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that if you specify a full path to coco's it will look there. Thus

```
NSString*fqn = [documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent@"<property_list_name>.plist"];
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:fqn];
```

have not tried this, but it should work.

EDIT : assumes .plist is in the project, but the .pvr.ccz is in documents dictionary. Assuming further that your texture is called "downloaded-hd.pvr.ccz", the project enables HD for devices, the following example should find your files:

```
NSString*textureFileName=@"downloaded-hd.pvr.ccz";
NSString*fqn = 
    [documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:textureFileName];
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] 
    addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"<property_list_name>.plist"
            textureFileName:fqn];
```

i think the -hd will be silently processed correctly.

Comment: The file not found is not the file that will be called directly, that is `.pvr.ccz`, when `CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<file_name>.png"]];` is called, Cocos2D would get this image from `.pvr.ccz` by the coordinate specified in `.plist`.

Comment: I just found my solution that is saving both `.plist` and `.pvr.ccz` at the same place. Your solution is also work and quite similar. Thank you very much.